# Calendar ó Date cual es la mejor a usa en Java

Tags: java, date, método, calendar

Me e dado cuenta que varios metodos de Date estan deprecados, cual seria mejor usar o se puede hacer una convinacion de ambos a la hora de necesitar usar los datos individuales de una fecha.

ejemplo:

```
public String getFechaInicio() {
    Date fechaInicio = new Date();
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTime(fechaInicio);
    return calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + (calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) +
                        "-" + calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
}
```

Comment: Si estás usando Java 8 o posterior, te recomiendo no usar ninguna de las dos. Java ha adolecido de una librería decente para manejar fechas hasta que apareció el paquete java.time

Answer (score 1):

Lo más adecuado es usar las clases del paquete [java.time](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/articles/java/paquete-java-time-2390472-esa.html).
Con tu ejemplo:

```
public String getFechaInicio() {
    LocalDate fechaInicio = LocalDate.now();
    return fechaInicio.getYear() + "-" + fechaInicio.getMonthValue() +
                        "-" + fechaInicio.getDayOfMonth();
}
```

o mejor aún:

```
public String getFechaInicio() {
    return LocalDate.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-HH-dd"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buenas en mi experiencia lo mejor es DateTime de apache: [apache joda time](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time)

Muy sencillo de usar. Te bajas la libreria y la importas, estas usando maven?

Aprovecho y te dejo algunos ejemplos de lo que podes hacer con esta libreria:

```
    new DateTime().minusDays()
    new DateTime().plusDays()
    new DateTime().plusSeconds()
    new DateTime().getWeekOfWeekyear()
    new DateTime().getHourOfDay()
```